# JavaScript better practice event listener or function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a dilemma between 2 preferred methods of operations:

1. Attaching an event listener when the body loads using jQuery:

   ```
    $(function(){ ....
   ```

   that will catch the form event.
2. adding `onblur` / `onkeyup` to the HTML code and create JS function definition.

What would be better practice?

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve by asking the question?

Comment: yes, my specific problem was which approach to take in JS/HTML development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your particular requirements, but in general I would say event listeners are better practice as this seperates your HTML from your javascript logic.

Therefore if you add a new HTML element, this will automatically use your event listener, rather than you having to explicitly set the event call each time.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the answer i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is the way I would go.

This allows you to separate the need to know JavaScript function names in the HTML or HTML generation.

That being said, you should keep the binding actions to HTML actions as loose as possible. You are essentially reversing the dependency of needing to know some attribute of your HTML element to bind to.

You may want to define your action methods and bind the events to them separately.